# Kendo DetailView Grid pass parameter with space

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, parameters, kendo-grid

I need to pass parameter with spaces in a [detail view](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/detailtemplate) in Kendo Grid.  This is the inner grid that reads parameter from "parent grid" as a row is selected.

How can I pass the "paramWithSpaces" as encoded string with spaces? For instance, something like "department name".

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Derp>()
    .Name("grid_#=paramWithSpaces#")
    .Columns(c =>
    {
        c.Bound(e => e.Col1);
        c.Bound(e => e.Col2);
        c.Bound(e => e.Col3);
        c.Bound(e => e.Col4);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Action", "Controller", new { param = "#=paramWithSpaces#" }))
    )
    .ToClientTemplate()
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace space with any unique character like _ (underscore) or any number like 0.
Because in name attribute it wont allow space. For binding purpose you can replace that character with a space again on server side.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  I just changed the #=paramWithSpaces# with #=uid# but that contains the uid from the parent row.